# Java Server Example Errors

Tags: java

Getting these errors in some java code

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot open port 8080
at servers.MultiThreadedServer.openServerSocket(MultiThreadedServer.java:61)
at servers.MultiThreadedServer.run(MultiThreadedServer.java:22)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:202)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:114)
at servers.MultiThreadedServer.openServerSocket(MultiThreadedServer.java:59)
... 2 more
     Exception in thread "main" Stopping Server
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at servers.MultiThreadedServer.stop(MultiThreadedServer.java:51)
at servers.Dispatch.main(Dispatch.java:18)
```

I made these files

**WorkerRunnable.java**

```
package servers;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

/**

*/
public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable{

protected Socket clientSocket = null;
protected String serverText   = null;

public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket, String serverText) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.serverText   = serverText;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        InputStream input  = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        output.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nWorkerRunnable: " +
                this.serverText + " - " +
                time +
                "").getBytes());
        output.close();
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Request processed: " + time);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //report exception somewhere.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
 }
```

**MultiThreadedServer.java**

```
package servers;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable{

protected int          serverPort   = 8080;
protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
protected boolean      isStopped    = false;
protected Thread       runningThread= null;

public MultiThreadedServer(int port){
    this.serverPort = port;
}

public void run(){
    synchronized(this){
        this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }
    openServerSocket();
    while(! isStopped()){
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(isStopped()) {
                System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
                return;
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Error accepting client connection", e);
        }
        new Thread(
            new WorkerRunnable(
                clientSocket, "Multithreaded Server")
        ).start();
    }
    System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
}


private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
    return this.isStopped;
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    this.isStopped = true;
    try {
        this.serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
    }
}

private void openServerSocket() {
    try {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 8080", e);
    }
}

}
```

**Dispatch.java**

```
 package servers;

 public class Dispatch {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MultiThreadedServer server = new MultiThreadedServer(9000);
    new Thread(server).start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Stopping Server");
    server.stop();

}

}
```

Comment: Check whether another process is listening to the port 8080 (if so stop that process and try again). Try "netstat -antp" if you are in Linux.

Comment: That \n\n should be \r\n for HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your machine's port `8080` being used by other program

**Terminate program that use port 8080**

You can find out the program via following command (Windows):

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:8080
```

Example output:

```
TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 8704
```

Then you can find the program using PID `8704` using Task Manager and terminate it.

Refer [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-check-and-identify-which-application-is-listening-or-opening-port-80-and-443-on-windows/) in more details.

**Use other port**

You can change the

```
protected int serverPort   = 8080;
```

to

```
protected int serverPort   = 8888;
```

Or

```
MultiThreadedServer server = new MultiThreadedServer(8888);
```

So it is use port `8888` instead of `8080`.

Comment: I have used Java a lot in the past couple of weeks. but I have never written a server/client application. How would I test this type of application at home if I do not have access to a server.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the port `8080` is already being used by another service in your computer (it's generally used by web servers, like [Tomcat](http://www.rescarta.com/index.php/rcsoft/rcfaqssec/13-rcwebfaq/35-tomcatport.html)). Try starting your server in another port number.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is error prone and misleading.  You're specifying the server port as `9000`, and printing it as `8080` in the exception block, and initializing it `8080` in the class declaration.  The real port thats in use is port `9000`, not `8080`.  Try another port - heck try `8080`.